# How to set parameters in Kafka-Bigquery Dataflow flex template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, aws-msk

I have been trying dataflow flex template to connect from Kafka consumer to Bigquery. Following is my configuration -

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run first-kafka --template-file-gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-us-east4/latest/flex/Kafka_to_BigQuery --region us-east4 --worker-region us-east4 --subnetwork <subnetwork-url> --parameters inputTopics=topic1,bootstrapServers=<bootstrap server>,outputTableSpec=<Bigquery table>,stagingLocation=gs://<xxx>/staging-dataflow,dataflowKmsKey=<CMS Key>,serviceAccount=XYZ@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

To connect to consumer security.protocol=SASL_SSL and it also uses username and password like this
xyz.conf

```
KafkaClient { org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="abcd" password="1234";};
```

I have JKS truststore file as well.

My question is how can i provide these configurations to dataflow template?

1. security.protocol = SASL_SSL
2. java.security.auth.login.config = xyz.conf
3. If client truststore JKS is required, then how can i provide this as well? (currently i have these in my cloud storage bucket)
   NOTE:My client machine is running on AWS MSK

Error I am getting without setting these configuration is -

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Java, and my purpose is different with you, but I hope the answer help you.

My purpose is setup `security.protocol = SSL` only.

1. Clone the repo: [DataflowTemplates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates)
2. Modify the code.
3. Read [the instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/kafka-to-bigquery/README_Kafka_to_BigQuery.md) for building the template.

In the step 2: Edit the [file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/kafka-to-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/KafkaToBigQuery.java)

```
LINE 68: import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs; // add this line

LINE 294: 
PCollectionTuple convertedTableRows =
    pipeline
        /*
         * Step #1: Read messages in from Kafka
         */
        .apply(
            "ReadFromKafka",
            readFromKafka(
                bootstrapServers,
                topicsList,
                ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder() // edited
                .put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest") // edited
                .put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL") // edited
                .build(), // edited
                null))
```

I believe [there are some clues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/kafka-to-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/kafka/consumer/SslConsumerFactoryFn.java) for setting key configs, but I didn't trace the code where to fill in the parameters.

Answer (score -2):

To provide custom Kafka client configurations, including `security.protocol`, `java.security.auth.login.config`, and truststore settings, to your Dataflow Flex Template when connecting to Kafka, you can use the `--parameters` flag to pass in additional configuration values. Here's how you can include these configurations in your `gcloud` command:

```bash
gcloud dataflow flex-template run first-kafka \
    --template-file-gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-us-east4/latest/flex/Kafka_to_BigQuery \
    --region us-east4 \
    --worker-region us-east4 \
    --subnetwork <subnetwork-url> \
    --parameters inputTopics=topic1,bootstrapServers=<bootstrap server>,outputTableSpec=<Bigquery table>,stagingLocation=gs://<xxx>/staging-dataflow,dataflowKmsKey=<CMS Key>,serviceAccount=XYZ@developer.gserviceaccount.com,\
    securityProtocol=SASL_SSL,loginConfigFile=xyz.conf,truststoreLocation=<gs://path/to/truststore.jks>
```

In this command, I've added three new parameters:

1. `securityProtocol`: This parameter allows you to specify the `security.protocol` configuration for Kafka, such as `SASL_SSL`.
2. `loginConfigFile`: This parameter is for the `java.security.auth.login.config` configuration and should point to your `xyz.conf` file.
3. `truststoreLocation`: This parameter should point to the location of your truststore JKS file in Google Cloud Storage. Make sure to replace `<gs://path/to/truststore.jks>` with the actual GCS path to your truststore.

Now, you need to modify your Dataflow pipeline code to read these parameters and set them in your Kafka consumer configuration.

Within your Dataflow pipeline code (likely in the `@Setup` method), you can access these parameters using the `RuntimeValueProvider` interface. Here's an example of how to retrieve these values and set them in your Kafka consumer configuration:

```java
@Setup
public void setup() {
    String securityProtocol = options.getSecurityProtocol();
    String loginConfigFile = options.getLoginConfigFile();
    String truststoreLocation = options.getTruststoreLocation();

    Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
    kafkaProps.put("security.protocol", securityProtocol);
    kafkaProps.put("java.security.auth.login.config", loginConfigFile);

    // Configure truststore (if required)
    if (truststoreLocation != null && !truststoreLocation.isEmpty()) {
        kafkaProps.put("ssl.truststore.location", truststoreLocation);
        // You may need to provide other truststore-related settings here
    }

    // Create Kafka consumer with the configured properties
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaProps);
    
    // Perform other Kafka consumer setup and processing
    // ...
}
```

This code reads the parameters passed to the Dataflow job, sets them in the Kafka consumer's properties, and configures the truststore if provided. Make sure your Dataflow pipeline code uses the `options` object to access the parameters passed to the job.

With these configurations in place, your Dataflow job should be able to connect to Kafka with the desired security settings and custom configurations.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Which file do i need to make these changes in "kafka-to-bigquery" template?
Moreover, after changes do i need to build image and store it in registry or we can trigger it directly?